# If conditional in mysql trigger?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers

Straight forward, i have problem using conditional state in trigger mysql.
There are 2 status, if the status is 'guest' then do something.. and else do another thing.

Here's what i already made :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update-gain` AFTER INSERT ON `payment`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
declare v_profit integer;
declare v_deposit integer;
declare v_status CHAR;

select (status) into v_status from item where item.id_item=new.id_item;
select sum(profit_owner) into v_profit from payment where payment.id_item=new.id_item;
select sum(profit_guest ) into v_deposit from payment where payment.id_item=new.id_item;

if v_status like 'guest' then
INSERT INTO gain
(gain.profit, gain.modal,gain.date)
VALUES
(v_profit,v_deposit,new.date)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
gain.profit = gain.profit+new.profit_owner,
gain.modal = gain.deposit+new.profit_guest;

else
INSERT INTO gain
(gain.profit,gain.tanggal)
VALUES
(v_profit,new.tgl_stok)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
gain.profit = gain.profit_owner+new.profit_owner;

end if;
END
```

So far i'm using 'like' clause, but the condition always true, even v_status is not 'guest'.

What did i do wrong here?
Thanks :)

Comment: did you try `set v_status = new.status`? I guess you will receive the default value here using your approach.

Comment: It would be useful if you post the structure of the tables and some sample data.

Comment: Well, 'gain' table doesn't have 'status' field. @Psi.

Comment: `CHAR` means `CHAR(1)`, so it will cut everything after the first letter (or throw an error). Not sure why your condition is always true and not always false, as `g` is never like `guest`. Are you sure it's not vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if v_status like 'guest' then
```

for

```
if v_status = 'guest' then
```

Comment: already changed before but still the problem exist. Always met the first conditional clause